# Finding the expectation of a linear combination of independent random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the observed fuel efficiency for one type of vehicle and $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ ​be the efficiency for a second type. Suppose these variables are independent and $X_i \sim N(20, 4)$ for $i = 1, 2$ and $Y_j \sim N(18, 9)$ for $j=1,2, 3$. Define a new random variable: $W = (X_1 + X_2)/2 - (Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3)/3 $.

Find $E[W]$

The work I have done thus far is attempting to re-write the equation to find a new form more amenable to computing the expectation.

$W=\frac{3(x_1+x_2 )}{6-(y_1+y_2+y_3 )}=\frac{3x_1+3x_2}{6-y_1-y_2-y_3 }= 3x_1 \frac{1}{(6-y_1-y_2-y_3 )}+3x_2 \frac{1}{[(6-y_1-y_2-y_3 )}$

$E[3x_1 \frac{1}{(6-y_1-y_2-y_3 )} + 3x_2 \frac{1}{(6-y_1-y_2-y_3 )}] = 3E[x_1]E[\frac{1}{(6-y_1-y_2-y_3 )}] + 3E[x_2]E[\frac{1}{(6-y_1-y_2-y_3 )}]$

From here, I am not sure how to obtain the expectation for $E[\frac{1}{6-y_1-y_2-y_3}]$

I am seeking some advice on how to approach this problem or input where I am going wrong when attempting to compute the expectation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "linearity of expectation". If you have random variables $X, Y$ and constant scalars $a, b$ then $E[aX + bY] = a E[X] + b E[Y]$. This is a very powerful result because it's always true even if the variables depend on each other in some confusing way.

Separately, you made some very strange mistake in the very first step of the work you've shown. You defined $W = \frac{X_1 + X_2}{2} - \frac{Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3}{3}$, but when you start to simplify, you somehow immediately write a totally different (much messier) expression:
$$W=\frac{3(x_1+x_2 )}{6-(y_1+y_2+y_3 )}.$$ I suspect you might be able to solve this once you fix that one weird mistake.

Comment: Thanks! Re-reading this and going back over the work I did I realized that I wrote the equation for W incorrectly when I transcribed the problem and turned a subtraction to a divide thus the weird expression.